# How to fetch records from multiple columns based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and there is one flag column. On the basis of the flag I have to fetch the rows from a table. The problem is; I need to handle with SQL query.

For example: I have table A. If a row's flag value is 'N' then I have to fetch all rows from table. If a row's flag value is 'Y' then only rows whose flag value is 'Y'.

```
id name flag
1  A     Y
2  B     N
3  C     N
4  D     N
```

for example if flag is 'Y' then query should return rows whose flag is 'Y' if 'N' then query should fetch all the records from the table.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data, the expected output and the query you have tried ?

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be helpful to get you the solution

Comment: So (@prashant chhetri), regarding your explanation quote 1. : " If I have falg value is 'N' then I have to fetch all rows from table if 'Y' then only rows whose flag value is 'Y'", and quote  2. : "for example if flag is 'Y' then query should return rows whose flag is 'Y' if 'N' then query should fetch all the records from the table." end qotes. Since you have both 'N' and 'Y' in your data what do you want as result: all rows or just rows flagged as 'Y'. Or did you forget to mention that you intend to enter a flag variable when running the query (or bind it) ???

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MAX()` here for a window function trick:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, MAX(flag) OVER () max_flag
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE max_flag = 'N' OR flag = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is expected as a result since there are both 'N' and 'Y' present in column FLAG. There is no instruction which one is "stronger", so to say, or maybe it will be  provided as a variable at execution time. Anyway, here is the code to do it in all three cases (assuming that FLAG column values could be either 'Y'  or 'N' or null)...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'A' "A_NAME", 'Y' "FLAG" From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'B', 'N' From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 'C', 'N' From Dual Union All 
          Select 4, 'D', 'N' From Dual 
        )
```

**1. if 'Y' flag is stronger then 'N' flag**

```sql
SELECT ID, A_NAME, Max(FLAG) "FLAG"
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY ID, A_NAME
HAVING Max(FLAG) = 'Y'
/*
ID  A_NAME  FLAG
--  ------  ----
 1  A       Y      */
```

**2. if 'N' flag is stronger then 'Y' flag**

```sql
SELECT ID, A_NAME, Max(FLAG) "FLAG"
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY ID, A_NAME
HAVING Min(FLAG) = 'N' OR Nvl(Max(FLAG), 'Y') = 'Y'
/*
ID  A_NAME  FLAG
--  ------  ----
 1  A       Y
 2  B       N
 3  C       N
 4  D       N      */
```

**3. if flag is entered at execution**

```sql
SELECT ID, A_NAME, Max(FLAG) "FLAG"
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY ID, A_NAME
HAVING Max(FLAG) = Case When :YourFlagVar = 'Y' Then 'Y' Else 'xxxx' End 
       OR
       (  Min(FLAG) = Case When :YourFlagVar = 'N' Then 'N' Else 'xxxx' End  
        OR 
          Nvl(Max(FLAG), 'Y') = Case When :YourFlagVar = 'N' Then 'Y' Else 'xxxx' End
       )
```

This results as **1. if** :YourFlagVar = '**Y**' and as **2. if** :YourFlagVar = '**N**'
... see it at --> https://dbfiddle.uk/Bs8RWR_L